# WooCommerce send order complete email automatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm faced with a little problem.
I need to send the Customer Invoice / Order Details email automatically when an order is completed.

I haven't found any action or filter to apply in this case an the internet is not useful. Has anyone an idea how to send this email when the order status switches?

Best regards!

Comment: As in you want to send a custom email or a woocommerce email?

Comment: @WilliamTurner the woocommerce mail. See the accepted answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook and `WC_Email_Customer_Invoice`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'mysite_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 1);

function mysite_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id ) {
   // Send invoice email to customer
   //use order ID as trigger value
   WC()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Invoice']->trigger($order_id);
}
```

Comment: @TobiasSchäfer I hope it works, please try share the result with us

Comment: added small correction, for folks may copy this directly. Works fine!