# Send an email to specific address when order complete

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I need an email to be automatically send to accounting with order details when order complete. This cannot be the same email that was send to customer on order complete as there must be Stripe fee included.

I've looked at WooCommerce e-mail hooks but I haven't found anything that would do what I want and there are tons of plugins which more or less have description that doesn't specify what I need.

My question is, does anybody have some experience with that? Can you suggest a plugin or can this be solved only with coding?

[This post offer some solution but that is just forwarding a customer invoice, if I'm not wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907856/woocommerce-send-order-complete-email-automatically)

Comment: You'd probably have to build this yourself using Stripe's API. You can listen to webhooks for a successful charge and look at all the details including the processing fee and send an email to yourself, or directly update your database or systems etc.

Comment: @karllekko, thx for your reply. Thought so, was still hoping for simpler solution. :)